# how can I make stickys header when the scroll intersects them?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code to make a sticky header. But it only works for the first element with the `.header` class. How can I make this effect for each of the elements with the `.header` class?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.querySelector(".header");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
html,body,h1{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.header{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background:white;
  
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header">title1</h1>
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
</div>

<h1 class="header">title2</h1>
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
</div>

<h1 class="header">title3</h1>
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officiis cupiditate animi temporibus, nisi error quas possimus nulla tempora perspiciatis distinctio maiores, quisquam perferendis. Nisi molestias eaque earum ullam optio.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need any JavaScript for this. Just use `position: sticky;` with `top: 0` on the `.header` class to make this work. Make sure you set the background to white so that the text does not overlap, either.

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wmL71xqu/2/

Comment: Nice ! I never see position:sticky

Comment: this is great! but how can I control the spacing between the content and the sticky, something like this: `.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
`

Comment: you can use `position:fixed; top:0` as well.

Comment: @MirzaIrtiza actually, that would put all the sticky headers at the top of the screen all the time. Sticky only does this once you have scrolled past it.